# php for each with comma separator except last

Tags: php

I am working on incorperating the jplayer html5 audio playlist

I'm using a foreach to generate the script element for each playlist item.
Everything is working as expected, Except I've included the comma in the loop, but I need a way to write the comma as separator except for last item.

here is what I've got so far to generate jplayer playlist.

```
<?php foreach( $songs as $song ): if( !empty($song) ): ?>{

        title:"Each Song Title",

        mp3:"Each song mp3 url"

    },<?php endif; endforeach; ?>
```

which gives me

```
    {

        title:"Partir",

        mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-09-Partir.mp3"

    },

    {

        title:"Thin Ice",

        mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-10-Thin-ice.mp3"

    },
    {

        title:"Ice man",

        mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-10-Thin-ice.mp3"

    },
```

This is my desired result

```
    {

        title:"Partir",

        mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-09-Partir.mp3"

    },

    {

        title:"Thin Ice",

        mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-10-Thin-ice.mp3"

    },
    {

        title:"Ice man",

        mp3:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/mp3/Miaow-10-Thin-ice.mp3"

    }
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: why dont you just `json_encode` it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I use [next()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.next.php) for it:

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
$copy = $arr;
foreach ($arr as $val) {
    echo $val;
    if (next($copy )) {
        echo ','; // Add comma for all elements instead of last
    }
}
```

Comment: a) `foreach` iterates over a copy of the array and b) `next()` moves the cursor. OK, it works, but it doesn't work, because of the reason you think it works ;) In fact you are iterating over two (identical) arrays at once and you stop, when you realise, that you are at the end of the second one.

Comment: At least it gives the expected result ^^

Comment: Isn't executing an "if" on each iteration of a very large loop slower than just removing the last comma?

Answer (score 4):

You mean JSON?

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

Also you can use array functions instead

```
// Create single items first
$array = array_map(
    function ($item) {
        return sprintf(
            '{title:"%s",mp3:"%s"}',
            $item['title'],
            $item['mp3']
        );
    },
    $array
);

// Then concatenate
echo implode(',', $array);
```

Just to make it complete: A `for`-solution

```
for ($n = count($array), $i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
    echo sprintf('{title:"%s",mp3:"%s"}', $array[$i]['title'], $array[$i]['mp3']) . ($i < $n-1 ? ',' : '');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you can also do, is rather than echo it directly to the browser, store it in a string first.

```
<?php 
$string = "";
foreach( $songs as $song ) { 
    if( !empty($song) )
    { 
        $string .= '
    {

        title:"Each Song Title",

        mp3:"Each song mp3 url"

    },

    ';
    }
 }
 $string = substr($string, 0, -1); //Removes very last comma.
 echo $string;
 ?>
```

This also allows it to be used elsewhere throughout your code, if needed.